# Firewall app for MacOS that I can quit

Tags: osx, macos, firewall

I know there is a few firewall solutions for Mac, I use one - "Little Snitch" and while it's great, it does not satisfy one of my requirements.

My use case is as follows:

I'm offline, maybe even in airplane mode, no network connectivity whatsoever and I'm running Mac on battery and just want to maximize its run time. I would like to quit as many apps as possible. Little Snitch would not let me quit/exit the app when/if I do not need it at the time. The only solution to unload it from memory is to uninstall the app.

Are there any firewall apps for MacOS that I can quit/exit when/if I no longer need it in memory?